# BIND9, name resolution with two views and networks

Tags: dns, bind

I have a BIND setup with two views, `internal` and `external`. `internal` responds to queries sent by hosts from the internal network, `external` responds to public queries.

Some hosts have only public addresses, so they have only `A` record in my public zone file.

But I would like to access (SSH) those hosts also from internal network without typing the whole domain. If my default `search` domain is `example.com`, for internal traffic to internal hosts I can write `ssh myhost` and it works fine (because it has an `A` private record in the internal zone file). But for external hosts I must write `ssh myotherhost.example.com` (they exists only in the external zone file).

Does BIND views have a way to accomplish this? I could add an `A` public record (public address) to my internal zone (private addresses) file, but this brakes the logic.

Best Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 1):

The idea of views is not to separate the authority of public vs private IP addresses.

The internal view can very well and should answer to queries about the names for private and public addresses.

The point of configuring views is *normally* not delivering to the outside details about your internal network, and as such the public view is authoritative for the names of the public IP addresses.